# Cross-thread operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I’m doing some stuffs in thread and I’m try to access the label property, but I can’t to set the property value.

```
lblDisplay.Visible = true;
```

I’m getting an error on this.
Error - Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblDisplay' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @karthiga: There are many posts which answers your question. Try to search inside ST before posting question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t directly access from a thread other than the thread it was created on. You can set that property value by using MethodInvoker.

```
lblDisplay.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { lblDisplay.Visible = true; }));
```

This the way you need to access the control in different thread.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `BeginInvoke` method on the form to set the variable on the same thread it's running on, for example:

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate{ lblDisplay.Visible = true; });
```

Most people will tell you to use the `Invoke` method instead but unless you absolutely NEED everything in the delegate to be run before any other code in the thread is executed you probably wont need it. `Invoke` will block the thread from processing any further until the delegate has completed, where as `BeginInvoke` will simply execute it in the thread the form is running in while simultaneously running the thread that began the invoke.

Answer (score 1):

I think you first need to Check whether its need to invoke or not ( In some other case that same code may not need to invoke) so...

```
if(lblDisplay.InvokeRequired) {
 lblDisplay.Invoke((Action)delegate{ lblDisplay.Visible = true; }); // For synchronous
 lblDisplay.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate{ lblDisplay.Visible = true; }) // For asynchronous
      }
else
{
lblDisplay.Visible=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.BeginInvoke` method with lambda :

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { lblDisplay.Visible = true; }));
```

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A `Control` can only be accessed within the thread that created it - the UI thread.

Try this,

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    lblDisplay.Visible = true;
}));
```